# SpriteKit: Overlayed nodes cannot be tapped

Tags: ios

I have multiple SKEffectNodes I use as layers to represent different screens e.g. main menu screen, game screen, game result screen. I attach children nodes to represent buttons, labels, etc... to their respective layers.

When one layer is visible, the previous is blurred with a low alpha in the background so it's slightly visible. When transitioning, the foreground will blur and tween the alpha to 0 while the background will blur and tween the alpha to 1. The foreground does not get recycled (I realize this may be part of the issue).

When the Game Screen is behind the Main Menu Screen, the Play button (Button: SKSpriteNode with isUserInteractionEnabled = true") on the main menu overlays an SKSpriteNode with "isUserInteractionEnabled = false" from the Game Screen. When I try tapping on the middle of the Play Button, it does not trigger the touchesEnded(...) method. But when I tap anywhere where the SKSpriteNode is not behind it, it triggers the Play button's touchesEnded(...) method.

I have a transitionInComplete and a transitionOutComplete methods I use to determine when a layer is fully visible / invisible and is active / inactive. I thought that this issue had something to do with the zPositioning, so I set the current layer's zPosition to 100 when transitionInComplete is called and zPosition to 0 when transitionOutComplete is called but this did not solve the problem. I do not touch any of the layer's components' (buttons, labels, etc) zPositions at this time.

Any ideas?

Edit (09/25/2018 @ 3:23 PM PST):
It's worth to note I do have swipe gestures enabled on the scene. The SKSpriteNodes react to swipe gestures.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with zPositioning.

The following post made me realize that there was overlap because of how zPositioning is calculated from parent to child:
[zPosition of SKNode relative to its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557879/zposition-of-sknode-relative-to-its-parent/31564783)